# Configuring application specific loggers fro EAR file

Tags: logging, war, jboss7.x, ear

Does anyone know how to configure application specific loggers for EAR file?

I am able to configure for WAR file. But if I wrap this war in an ear file, then loggers will not work.

Any help is appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should just be able to use the logging subsystem. Are you attempting to use a lo4j configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss AS 7.1.x you'll need to [exclude](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) the servers version of log4j. For an EAR specifically both your log4j configuration file and your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` need to be in the `META-INF` directory of your EAR.

In JBoss 7.2.x and EAP 6.x all you need to do is have your log4j configuration file in the `META-INF` directory. There is no need to exclude the servers log4j or bundle your own.

Comment: I have placed jboss-deployment-structure.xml in META-INF directory of EAR file. And I have placed log4j.xml in lib directory of ear file. Previously I had places log4j.xml file in META-INF but it dint work. So I moved to lib directory. Even that is not working